# Cannot load ldap3 python module in ExecuteScript processor

Tags: jython, apache-nifi, ldap3

I am trying to run a python script in a NiFi ExecuteScript processor. This script uses the **ldap3** library from: https://pypi.org/project/ldap3/. I am aware that the processor runs Jython, and that I am unable to use compiled code, `.so` files, etc. but I noted that the library claims to be:

> A strictly RFC 4510 conforming LDAP V3 pure Python client library

I have defined the path to the folder containing the library in the processor's **PROPERTIES** tab, using

```
Script Engine    : python
Script File      : /mnt/path_to_my_scripts/run.py
Script Body      :
Module Directory : /mnt/path_to_my_libs
```

...where the ldap3 library folder is:

```
/mnt/path_to_my_libs/ldap3
```

When I start the processor I get the following error message:

> 16:17:32 GMT - server.my.domain:9091 - ERROR ExecuteScript[id=xxxx]
>   Failed to process session due to
>   org.apache.nifi.processor.exception.ProcessException:
>   javax.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:
>   org/scijava/jython/shaded/javax/xml/bind/DatatypeConverter in 
>   at line number 5: javax.script.ScriptException:
>   javax.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:
>   org/scijava/jython/shaded/javax/xml/bind/DatatypeConverter in 
>   at line number 5

Sure enough, line number 5 in the scipt is:

```
import ldap3
```

I have other scripts running successfully which do *not* use ldap3.

Comment: I have just noticed this: http://bugs.jython.org/issue2663

Comment: Are you running Apache NiFi on Java 8 or Java 9? The current release of NiFi (1.6.0) is not compatible with Java 9. There is [work underway](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/NIFI-5174) to make future releases of NiFi run on Java 9.

Comment: I would hope a compatible version, but I'll have to check when I'm back in the office...

Comment: Unless... you know of a better way to run LDAP queries from NiFi, although that might be better asked as a separate question.

Comment: @Andy, this environment is **nifi-1.5.0-RC1** on **Java 1.8.0_121**.